# Defining types in typescript

Tags: typescript, type-declaration

I am brand new to the world of typescript and web design, so to put my foot in the door I am writing a program that upon loading and reloading, it will output a random car. An example output would be the following:

> Number of doors: 4 Number of Cylinders: 4 Type of Transmission: FWD Type of Car Body: SUV

There are other results you could get, but this is just an example of the layout.

The code I have in my typescript file is below:

```
class Car {
    car: string;
    door: number;
    cylinder: number;
    transmission: string;
    body: string;
    element: HTMLElement;

    constructor(door: number, cylinder: number, transmission: string, body: string) {
        this.car = door + " " + cylinder + " " + transmission + " " + body;
    }

}

interface FullCar {
    door: number;
    cylinder: number;
    transmission: string;
    body: string;
}

function randomCarGenerator(car: FullCar) {

    return "Number of Doors: " + car.door + "Number of Cylinders: " + car.cylinder + "Type of Transmission: " + car.transmission + "Type of Car Body: " + car.body;

}

var randomBody = ['Coupe', 'Sedan', 'Wagon', 'SUV'];
var randomDoor1 = [2, 4, 5];
var randomDoor2 = [2, 4];
var randomCylinder = [2, 3, 4];
var randomTransmission1 = ['AWD', 'Standard', 'FWD'];
var randomTransmission2 = ['Standard', 'FWD'];

var body = randomBody[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomBody.length)];
if (body == 'Coupe') {
    var door = 2;
    var cylinder = randomCylinder[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomCylinder.length)];
    var transmission = randomTransmission2[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomTransmission2.length)];

    var car = new Car(door, cylinder, transmission, body);
    document.body.innerHTML = randomCarGenerator(car);
}
else if (body == 'Sedan' || body == 'Wagon') {
    var door = randomDoor1[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomDoor1.length)];
    var cylinder = randomCylinder[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomCylinder.length)];
    var transmission = randomTransmission1[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomTransmission1.length)];

    var car = new Car(door, cylinder, transmission, body);
    document.body.innerHTML = randomCarGenerator(car);
}
else {
    var door = randomDoor2[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomDoor2.length)];
    var cylinder = randomCylinder[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomCylinder.length)];
    var transmission = randomTransmission1[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomTransmission1.length)];

    var car = new Car(door, cylinder, transmission, body);
    document.body.innerHTML = randomCarGenerator(car);

}
```

When I run this, the result that I get is

> Number of doors: undefined Number of Cylinders undefined etc etc

My question: Is there a problem with how I am declaring the declaring the values? Or is there a completely different issue going on that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Car {
    car: string;
    door: number;
    cylinder: number;
    transmission: string;
    body: string;
    element: HTMLElement;

    constructor(door: number, cylinder: number, transmission: string, body: string) {
        this.car = door + " " + cylinder + " " + transmission + " " + body;
    }

}
```

Here you:

1. Define a bunch of fields on the class
2. Take in constructor parameters with the same name
3. Set one of the class fields
4. Leave all the other class fields uninitialized

Then in this function

```
function randomCarGenerator(car: FullCar) {

    return "Number of Doors: " + car.door + "Number of Cylinders: " + car.cylinder + "Type of Transmission: " + car.transmission + "Type of Car Body: " + car.body;

}
```

You read all the fields that you never initialized in the first place.

You could fix this by initializing the fields:

```
class Car {
    car: string;
    door: number;
    cylinder: number;
    transmission: string;
    body: string;
    element: HTMLElement;

    constructor(door: number, cylinder: number, transmission: string, body: string) {
        this.car = door + " " + cylinder + " " + transmission + " " + body;
        this.door = door;
        this.cylinder = cylinder;
        // etc for the other fields
    }

}
```

A nice syntactic shortcut in TypeScript is that you can use an access modifier (e.g. `public`) to make these fields automatically:

```
class Car {
    car: string;
    // Unused, not sure what you intend to do with this one
    element: HTMLElement;

    constructor(public door: number, public cylinder: number, public transmission: string, public body: string) {
        this.car = door + " " + cylinder + " " + transmission + " " + body;
    }

}
```